# I want to test a method in the service class that performs a sort on the results from a repository call

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

For context this is a Spring Boot app using an H2 database:

My `service` class returns the results I want from my `repository interface` which extends `CrudRepository<Organisation, Integer>`.

Within the service class, I have a method that sorts a list of entity objects via ascending order.

In production code, the data I intend to sort comes from the repository call `.findAll()` in the service class below.

```
public List<Organization> findOrganizationAscending(){
       organizationRepository.findAll().forEach(organization -> sort(organizations));
        return organizations;
    }
```

I want to write a test for this method that assesses if the method is correctly returning a list in ascending order.

I have tested on Postman and can visually confirm that it works but I want to have unit tests surrounding the method for future security.

Should I be writing an integration test or a unit test?

I feel that a unit test is more appropriate because I want to check if my sort is working or not.

But how do I generate supporting data for the test?

Here is what I have tried so far, but I receive an NPE from the repository call which ultimately leads to test failures.

Any suggestions will be welcomed on how I should be setting up the data to test this method correctly.

```
private OrganizationService organizationService;
    @MockBean
    OrganizationRepository organizationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    void testGetOrganizationAsc() {

        // given
        List<Organization> expectedOrganizationsList = ascendingListOfOrganisations();
        List<Organization> actualOrganizationsList = unorganisedList();

        testEntityManager.persist(expectedOrganizationsList);
        testEntityManager.persist(actualOrganizationsList);


        given(organizationRepository.findAll().equals(actualOrganizationsList));

        // when

        when(organizationService.getOrganizationAsc()).thenReturn(expectedOrganizationsList);

        // then
        assertEquals(expectedOrganizationsList, actualOrganizationsList);

    }

    private List<Organization> unorganisedList() {
        Organization organization1 = new Organization(1, "Zoopla");
        Organization organization2 = new Organization(1, "Apple");
        Organization organization3 = new Organization(1, "Micro-Soft");
        Organization organization4 = new Organization(1, "Dell");

        List<Organization> unorganisedList = new ArrayList<>();
        unorganisedList.add(organization1);
        unorganisedList.add(organization2);
        unorganisedList.add(organization3);
        unorganisedList.add(organization4);

        return unorganisedList;
    }

    private List<Organization> ascendingListOfOrganisations() {
        Organization organization1 = new Organization(1, "Zoopla");
        Organization organization2 = new Organization(1, "Apple");
        Organization organization3 = new Organization(1, "Micro-Soft");
        Organization organization4 = new Organization(1, "Dell");

        List<Organization> organizationsList = new ArrayList<>();
        organizationsList.add(organization1);
        organizationsList.add(organization2);
        organizationsList.add(organization3);
        organizationsList.add(organization4);

        Collections.sort(organizationsList);
        return organizationsList;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can combine a mocking frame work, and write unit tests for your endpoints that rely on "fake" data coming from fake "providers". But thing is: doing that for Spring with dependency injection is simply complicated. So, instead of trying to go "trial and error": pick up a good tutorial that explains how to do all of that, **understand** stuff, and then apply to your problem. See here for example: https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/guide-spring-boot-controller-tests/

Comment: I have written controller tests to test the end-point calls but thought I needed to be testing the method in the service class as it was performing a separate job, the sorting of the data returned from the repository call.